# Notify users of updates, facebook app

Tags: facebook

I want to know how to get that little bubble next to your application, that lets the user know how many updates have occurred in the app.  I can't find this anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set a counter. Have a look at this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas#bookmarks for more info (there's also an example).